# Callback function in igniter datatables is not working

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, callback, datatables

I am using igniter datatables in my code for datatables with server side processing.My code is like :

```
public function datatable()
    {
        $this->datatables->select("
                            insight_worksheet.id,
                            insight_worksheet.workingDate,
                            insight_worksheet.reason,
                            ...                                
                            insight_worksheet.worksheet_status
                          ")
                  ->from("insight_worksheet")
                  ->edit_column('Actions', '$1', 'callback_test(insight_worksheet.id,insight_worksheet.worksheet_status)')
                  ...
                  ->join("insight_status","status.id=worksheet.status","left");

        echo $this->datatables->generate();

    }
   public function test($id,$worksheetStatus){
    return "srimanta";
}
```

in my view page for `Actions` column direct string `callback_test(insight_worksheet.id,insight_worksheet.worksheet_status)`
is showing instead of actual work whereas for other columns, showing exact data.
For time being I put two functions in my controller class.

Could you please let me know the issue in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the callback function test in a helper file.

Your model file:

```
public function datatable()
    {
        $this->datatables->select("
                            insight_worksheet.id,
                            insight_worksheet.workingDate,
                            insight_worksheet.reason,
                            ...                                
                            insight_worksheet.worksheet_status
                          ")
                  ->from("insight_worksheet")
                  ->edit_column('Actions', '$1', 'test(insight_worksheet.id,insight_worksheet.worksheet_status)')
                  ...
                  ->join("insight_status","status.id=worksheet.status","left");

        echo $this->datatables->generate();

    }
```

your helper file:

```
public function test($id,$worksheetStatus){
    return "srimanta";
}
```